# Excel VBA Can't save file name with variable holding date value

Tags: excel, file, vba

I have some code that copys and pastes the current worksheet to a blank new workbook, and then saves it depending on the values of some cells (stored in variables).

Specifically, these are Site, Client, and Date visited.

It all works fine with site and client, however when I include the date variable in the filename to save, it throws an error: Runtime error 76 - Path not found.

I'd appreciate any help/advise.

```
Sub Pastefile()

Dim client As String
Dim site As String
Dim visitdate As String
client = Range("B3").Value
site = Range("B23").Value
screeningdate = Range("B7").Value

Dim SrceFile
Dim DestFile

SrceFile = "C:\2013 Recieved Schedules\schedule template.xlsx"
DestFile = "C:\2013 Recieved Schedules" & "\" & client & " " & site & " " & visitdate  & ".xlsx"

FileCopy SrceFile, DestFile

ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
Range("A1:I37").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Schedules\2013 Recieved Schedules" & "\" & client & " " & site & " " &     visitdate & ".xlsx", UpdateLinks:= _
0
Range("A1:I37").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: If the date contains `/` they will be interpreted as part of a path. What does `msgbox "C:\Schedules\2013 Recieved Schedules" & "\" & client & " " & site & " " &     visitdate & ".xlsx"` look like

Comment: Ah you're right, thanks for the heads up. I've made sure these were formatted as eg "01 january 2013" though, assuming it wouldn't trip me up. How can I avoid this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. It seems that, in fact, your code is defective. Do you see that you've mentioned screeningdate instead of he declared variable visitdate above? It would be good running your code using the Debug Step-By-Step (F8) instead of using F5 to check it thoroughly. Hope this tiny bit of idea helps you do better coding :-)

Comment: as your file count raises you will realize that its a bad approach to save your files with such extended names. i recommend saving it into folders with names i.e. clients, site, visit date. In a long run - this will be much easier for you to do any type of searching or/and analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using dates in file names, you never want to rely on the default textual representation of the date, because that depends on the current locale.

You should store the date as date in the first place, and explicitly format it in a safe way for the file name:

```
Dim visitdate As Date
visitdate = Range("b7").Value

dim visitdate_text as string
visitdate_text = Format$(visitdate, "yyyy\-mm\-dd")
```

You might also consider removing any special characters like `\` from your other values, such as `client` and `site`. Otherwise the problem might arise again.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, both issues have been rectified and now all works well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion of code rewrite:

```
Sub Pastefile()

Dim client As String
Dim site As String
Dim visitdate As String
client = Range("B3").Value
site = Range("B23").Value
visitdate = Range("B7").Value

Dim SrceFile
Dim DestFile

If IsDate(visitdate) Then

SrceFile = "C:\2013 Received Schedules\schedule template.xlsx"
DestFile = "C:\2013 Received Schedules" & "\" & Trim(client) & " " & Trim(site) & " " & Str(Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")) & ".xlsx"

If Trim(Dir("C:\2013 Received Schedules\schedule template.xlsx")) <> "" Then
FileCopy SrceFile, DestFile
Else
MsgBox (SrceFile & " is not available in the folder")
GoTo EndCode
End If

Range("A1:I37").Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"C:\Schedules\2013 Received Schedules" & "\" & client & " " & site & " " & visitdate & ".xlsx", UpdateLinks:= 0
Range("A1:I37").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close

Else
MsgBox ("Please input the correct date in cell B7")
ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Activate
End If
EndCode:
End Sub
```